# PSEXEC runs successfully via command prompt but fails in ASP .Net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, psexec

I'm trying to run a command on remote machine using PSEXEC tool, it runs successfully using command prompt but it fails in an asp.net project showing the following output error.

> PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark
>   Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> The handle is invalid.
>
> > Connecting to lnxdevx...
> >
> > Starting PSEXESVC service on lnxdevx...
> >
> > Connecting with PsExec service on lnxdevx...
> >
> > Error deriving session key:.

Here is my sample c# code.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx \\\\lnxdevx -i -d -w \"C:\\DIRECTORY\" cmd.exe /C dir";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string errormessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Did you try changing UseShellExecute to true? (which seems to be the default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have to open `psexec`, but `cmd` and from there you run psexec.

The code you're trying to do is wrong too, you need to use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"; \\if it is in System32
startInfo.Arguments = "psexec -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx \\machine *your stuff*";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I'm not testing, but I'm quite sure this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is solving the problem, there is a better solution (at least without involving cmd).

Go to the app pool -> `Advanced Settings` -> Section `"Process Model"` -> `"Load User Profile"`.

The default is `false`. When you change it to `true`, everything should work.

A bit more of what there is (more of an interpretation, further research is needed).

- psexec and all tools from SysInternals require EULA to be accepted. This can be solved by calling them with `-accepteula` see [psexec at ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html)
- this should be saved in the registry. You have to have a profile for this to be read.

Based on https://nigglingaspirations.blogspot.com/2015/04/psexec-error-deriving-session-key.html